# Insert XElements using LINQ Select?

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have a source piece of xml into which I want to insert multiple elements which are created dependant upon certain values found in the original xml

At present I have a sub which does this for me:

```
<Extension()>
Public Sub AddElements(ByVal xml As XElement, ByVal elementList As IEnumerable(Of XElement))

    For Each e In elementList
        xml.Add(e)
    Next

End Sub
```

And this is getting invoked in a routine as follows:

```
Dim myElement = New XElement("NewElements")

myElement.AddElements(
     xml.Descendants("TheElements").
     Where(Function(e) e.Attribute("FilterElement") IsNot Nothing).
     Select(Function(e) New XElement("NewElement", New XAttribute("Text", e.Attribute("FilterElement").Value))))
```

Is it possible to re-write this using Linq syntax so I don't need to call out to the Sub AddElements but could do it all in-line

Many Thx

Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
Dim outputxml = 
   New XElement("NewElements",
      xml.Descendants("TheElements").
      Where(Function(e) e.Attribute("FilterElement") IsNot Nothing).
      Select(Function(e) _
         New XElement("NewElement", 
            New XAttribute("Text",e.Attribute("FilterElement").Value)
         )
      )
   )
```

`XElement` and `XAttribute` have constructors which (in addition to the element or attribute name) accept an arbitrary number of objects (which themselves can be queries or other `IEnumerables`).  Anything you pass to the constructor is added as content.

You may also want to look into XML-literals, which make this much more readable but essentially do the same thing.

With [XML Literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx), it looks like this:

```
dim outputxml = 
   <NewElements><%=   
      From e In xml...<TheElements> 
      Where e.@FilterElement IsNot Nothing 
      Select <NewElement Text=<%= e.@FilterElement %>/>
   %></NewElements>
' you can embed names and attribute values too
```

- `<%=` `%>`  embeds a VB expression's value in XML
- `xml...<elemname>` selects descendants of xml called elemname
- 'elem.@attrname` gets the value of an attribute

It's almost XQuery ;-).

Comment: @slf: It's all compile-time type-checked too, which is handy, since I've never written a VB-program in my life, merely pined for exactly that feature :-)